# Exclude certain bots when sorting through Apache server logs

Tags: bash, apache, bots, user-agent

I have a bash script that sorts the highest hits on my server logs, and prints the IP address and user agent:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | awk -F'|' '{print $5 $11}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -30
```

It prints out a result like this:

```
COUNT   IP Address  User Agent

37586  66.249.73.223  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
23960  84.132.153.226  "-" <--- I do need to see things like this
13246  17.58.103.219  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)" <--- But not this
10572  66.249.90.191  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246 Mozilla/5.0"
 9505  66.249.73.223  "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
 5157  66.249.73.193  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I am not concerned with bots such as Googlebot, Bingbot, Applebot, etc. Is there a way I can get the same format, but excluding these friendly bots?

I am able to exclude Googlebot with:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | awk -F'|' '{print $5 $11}' | grep -v "Googlebot" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -30
```

But I would like to exclude multiple bots.

I also did:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | awk -F'|' '{print $5 $11}' | grep -v "Googlebot" | grep -v "bingbot" | grep -v "Applebot" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -30
```

which seems to work, but is that proper bash syntax to pipe several greps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `grep -F -v -e <phrase1> -e <phrase2> ... -e <phraseN>`
as in the following:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | awk -F'|' '{print $5 $11}' | grep -F -v -e "Googlebot" -e "bingbot" -e "Applebot" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -30
```

`-F` tells grep to treat the search strings as a fixed string ... this is usually *much* faster than using regular expressions

`-e` allows you to specify an expression. Using multiple `-e` flags lets you combine multiple expressions for use in a single grep command.

Alternatively, you can use a "blacklist" file, and do something like the following:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | awk -F'|' '{print $5 $11}' | grep -F -f blacklist.txt -v | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -30
```

where the contents of blacklist.txt are:

```
Applebot
Googlebot
bingbot
```

... the benefit to this is that when you find a new entry you want to ignore, you can just add it to the blacklist instead of modifying your script ... it's also quite readable.

**edit**: You can also move the `-r` argument to your first `sort` and avoid the second call altogether. Also, because you're using `awk`, you could get rid of grep altogether (mind you, at the cost of using regexes, but since it's *already* processing every line in the file, you might save more time on the i/o):

```
cat /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | awk -F'|' '!/Applebot|Googlebot|bingbot/{print $5 $11}' | sort -nr | uniq -c | head -30
```

I would also suggest getting rid of the leading cat, because `awk` will open the file for reading without modification (unless you tell it to modify the file):

```
awk -F'|' '!/Applebot|Googlebot|bingbot/{print $5 $11}' /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | sort -nr | uniq -c | head -30
```

and since you know the location of the fields, you could also use `sed` which will be faster than using `awk` ... I leave that as an exercise to the reader (just keep in mind the indexed search results: `ls | sed -n 's/\(.*\)\.txt/\1/p'` results in all the '*.txt' files being printed out without their file extension)

Comment: I'm dealing with significantly smaller logs, but since I would like to be efficient no matter the size, I appreciate your answer much more since you gave me insight on the speed of your method. I will most definitely use this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that I could be of some assistance, and thanks for accepting the answer! I've spent a fair amount of time on resource constrained systems and processing large logs, so I've picked up a few tricks and tools to optimize along the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a much cleaner way to do it instead of multiple 'grep -v'. I used egrep:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/proxy.example.com.access.log | awk -F'|' '{print $5 $11}' | egrep -v "Googlebot|bingbot|Applebot" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -30
```

Unless someone has a better way, this works perfectly for me.

Comment: `egrep` comes with a performance hit that you can do without. At one point I was using egrep on some server logs and switched to the `grep -F -f blacklist.txt -v` approach and my log processing time dropped from about 5 minutes to about 12 seconds. check out my answer above for more details pertaining to your usage :-)